# How to catch android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, exception

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how do I catch this particular exception in my code? i.e, in my Catch block, what should be the catch keyword?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `catch(Resources.NotFoundException e)`. The `$` in your stack trace just means `NotFoundException` is a nested class in `Resources`.

You could import the fully qualified class for `NotFoundException` - that is, `android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException` - and just use `NotFoundException` in the `catch`, but it's arguably better for readability and comprehension to include the containing class for such a generically named `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException.html)

```
 try {
                drawable = Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```